# Web server cannot understand the URL format

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I am trying to migrate my CakePHP website from my local development server to the NetworkSolutions servers. I have overcome some of the problems, but there is one that I am unable to find a solution to, both on the internet and through trial and error.

I have a controller called "DonationController". The web server understands my request when I call the url `prefix.website.com/Donation.php` but cannot understand it when I remove the `.php`. 
Even more frustratingly, I also pass need to pass it an argument "incoming" - the url for this is `prefix.website.com/Donation/incoming` - which it also cannot understand.

When passing it these URLs, it gives me a 400 Error with the message

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand
```

The error log on the server logs this error as

```
[Sat Jan 04 01:49:03 2014][error] [client X.X.X.X] Invalid URI in request POST /Donation/incoming HTTP/1.0
```

I thought it had something to do with the .htaccess file, which currently looks like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^([^.?]+).json(.*)$ app/webroot/$1.php$2 [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can try and get the server to understand my requests? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue did not stem from the root file, but from the app/webroot/index.php file. The .htaccess in that folder was not RewriteBase-ing at `/app/webroot/` but was rebasing it at the root of the server. Simply adding the line `RewriteBase /app/webroot/` in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` section of the `.htaccess` file in the `app/webroot/` folder and adding the line `RewriteBase /webroot/` in the `.htaccess` file in the `app` folder did the trick.